# Angular 4 ngfor or ngif

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I don't know what to use for my problem.

I'm getting some information from my HTTP request, and I need to show a prerequisite from a Product when it has a prerequisite. When it doesn't have it I want it to show me a static message like `<h1>Test</h1>`.

**This is my Typescript**

```
  public getAllProducts() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .get(
          `${this.kioskservice.getAPIUrl()}products/?apikey=${this.kioskservice.getAPIKey()}&format=json`
        )
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => {
              this.config = res.json();
              // Get all product names
            if (this.config && this.config.length) {
              this.names = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < this.config.length; i++) {
                this.names.push(this.config[i]['Name']);
              }
              } 
              // Get all preruiquisites of the products
              if (this.config && this.config.length) {
                  this.prerequisites = [];
                  for (let i = 0; i < this.config.length; i++) {
                      this.prerequisites.push(this.config[i]['Prerequisites']);
                  }
              }
              console.log(this.prerequisites);
            resolve();
          },
          msg => {
            throw new Error("Couldn't get all Bookings: " + msg);
          }
        );
    });
  }
  public getNames() {
    return this.names
    }

  public getPrerequisites() {
    return this.prerequisites
    }
}
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<li *ngFor="let prerequisite of productservice.getPrerequisites()">
    <i>{{prerequisite}}</i>
</li>
<li *ngFor="let prerequisite of !productservice.getPrerequisites()">
    <i>TEST</i>
</li>
```

The HTML above will show me all 40 Objects that I receive from my HTTP request, but only 4 of those 40 have a Prerequisite text so I will get 36  empty `<i>` elements and 4 `<i>` elements with the prerequisite text in it.

**UPDATE**

[Image of Array of Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGz9G.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `*ngFor` to loop over the array, then use `*ngIf` to decide what to show.

```
<li *ngFor="let prerequisite of productservice.getPrerequisites()">
    <i *ngIf="prerequisite">{{prerequisite}}</i>
    <i *ngIf="!prerequisite">TEST</i>
</li>
```

Comment: Well, I put a generic condition because I don't know what kind of shape your data has. I assume that `productservice.getPrerequisites()` returns an array of objects, some objects will have a property and some won't, and that property is what you need to use in your *ngIf` to decide whether to show the first `<i>` or the second one

Comment: Yes that is completely what I want to achieve and how it works. 
I will update my post with a picture so you can see what the Array of Objects looks like